# How to get current user from IHubContext in SignalR?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

Suppose in some class library I have access to a specific `HubContext`:

`IHubContext ctx = connectionManager.GetHubContext<MyAwesomeHub>();`

How do I get access to the current authenticated .`User` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The GetHubContext method is normally used for sending messages from a background thread to a client (or many/all clients) so by definition won't have a SignalR user backing it.